# How to keep background-color in the status?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is the code

```
  edate = get_field('expire_date');
      $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d');
      $currentMonth = date('M');
      $earlier = new DateTime($edate);
      $later = new DateTime($currentDateTime);

     $daysrem = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a");
     
     $status = get_field('status');
    ?>
            <tr>
            <td class=""><?php the_field('expire_date')?></td>
            <td><?php echo $daysrem; ?></td>
            <td class="<?php the_field('status') ?>"><?php the_field('status') ?></td>
        </tr>
```

If the expire date is the current month the status should change to a background color of orange.
How to do it, Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compare the months and if the same, add 'orangeClassName' to a php variable:

```
$tdStyle = ($currentMonth == date('M',strtotime(the_field('expire_date')))) ? 'orangeClassName' : '';
```

then include that variable in your :

```
<td class="<?php echo $tdStyle;?>"><?php the_field('expire_date')?></td>
```

and add the relevant class to your css:

```
.orangeClassName {background:orange;}
```

*Note that this is only checking if the months are the same, so 04-2020 == 04-2019 would also return true*